# Do Linux and macOS have an `OfferVirtualMemory` counterpart?

Tags: linux, macos, caching, mmap

Windows, starting with a certain unspecified update of Windows 8.1, has the excellent [`OfferVirtualMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-offervirtualmemory) and [`ReclaimVirtualMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-reclaimvirtualmemory) system calls which allow memory regions to be "offered" to the OS. This removes them from the working set, reduces the amount of physical memory usage that is attributed to the calling process, and puts them onto the *standby* memory list of the program, but without ever swapping out the contents anywhere.

(Below is a brief and rough explanation of what those do and how standby lists work, to help people understand what kind of system call I'm looking for, so skip ahead if you already know all of this.)

### Quick standby list reference

Pages in the standby list can be returned back to the working set of the process, which is when their contents are swapped out to disk and the physical memory is used for housing a fresh allocation or swapping in memory from disk (if there's no available "dead weight" zeroed memory on the system), or no swapping happens and the physical memory is returned to the same virtual memory region they were first removed from, sidestepping the swapping process while still having reduced the working set of the program to, well, the memory it's actively working on, back when they were removed from the working set and put into the standby list to begin with.

Alternatively, if another program requests physical memory and the system doesn't have zeroed pages (if no program was closed recently, for example, and the rest of RAM has been used up with various system caches), physical memory from the standby list of a program can be zeroed, removed from the standby list, and handed over to the program which requested the memory.

### Back to memory offering

Since the offered memory never gets swapped out if, upon being removed from the standby list, it no longer belongs to the same virtual memory segment (removed from standby by anything other than [`ReclaimVirtualMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-reclaimvirtualmemory)), the reclamation process can fail, reporting that the contents of the memory region are now undefined (uninitialized memory has been fetched from the program's own standby list or from zeroed memory). This means that the program will have to re-generate the contents of the memory region from another data source, or by rerunning some computation.

The practical effect, when used to implement an intelligent computation cache system, is that, firstly, the reported working set of the program is reduced, giving a more accurate picture of how much memory it *really* needs. Secondly, the cached data, which can be re-generated from another region of memory, can be quickly discarded for another program to use that cache, without waiting for the disk (and putting additional strain on it, which adds up over time and results in increased wear) as it swaps out the contents of the cache, which aren't too expensive to recreate.

One good example of a use case is the render cache of a web browser, where it can just re-render parts of the page upon request, and has little to no use in having those caches taking up the working set and bugging the user which high memory usage. Pages which aren't currently being shown are the moment where this approach may give the biggest theoretical yield.

### The question

Do Linux and macOS have a comparable API set that allows memory to be marked as discardable at the memory manager's discretion, with a fallible system call to lock that memory back in, declaring the memory uninitialized if it was indeed discarded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux 4.5 and later has `madvise` with the `MADV_FREE`, the memory may be replaced with pages of zeros anytime until they are next written.

To lock the memory back in write to it, then read it to check if it has been zeroed. This needs to be done separately for every page.

Before Linux 4.12 the memory was freed immediately on systems without swap.

You need to take care of compiler memory reordering so use `atomic_signal_fence` or equivalent in C/C++.

Comment: Oh nice, that seems quite close to what I'm looking for. Just to clarify, `MADV_NORMAL` is how I'd suspend the effects of `MADV_FREE`, right?

Comment: No, `MADV_NORMAL` is not reverse of `MADV_FREE`.  The reverse is writing to the memory.

Comment: Oh, so the moment I perform a write to the page, the `MADV_FREE` state is removed and if I then repopulate the content of the page, it's guaranteed to never be discarded via `MADV_FREE` logic again until I call `madvise` with `MADV_FREE` a second time, is that right?

Comment: Yes.   You need to take care of compiler memory reordering so use `atomic_signal_fence` or equivalent in C/C++.